# ViewPager's current item is always set to 0 when activity resumes

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an arrayList which is an input to viewpager adapter. When I slides the viewpager and press back button or whenever activity resumes, Its index is set back to 0. Where can I save view pagers state ? or is there any work around to save its state ?

Comment: You can use non-ui fragment to save state of view pagers

Comment: use Sharedpreferences?

Comment: Application class can also be used this is not right approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int lastPos = prefs.getInt("lastPos", 0);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastPos);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("lastPos", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    editor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope will help you!

Comment: This approach works, but you should do it in `onResume` and `onPause` instead of `onCreate` and `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override this method in FragmentpagerAdapter

```
@Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object);
        }
```

then you need to remove super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object); this line

from your source code..hope this will work for you, raise the answer if you find it helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Pls try below code 
Take static int in your activity

```
private static int lastSelectedPos =0;
```

in onCreate of your Activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    // on your view pager instance set previos selected index
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastSelectedPos);
}
```

Override onDestroy of your Activity

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    lastSelectedPos =viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```